# Finding lines with length of 0.0 inside polygon with Python script in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgsfeaturerequest

I have a vector layer (PostGIS) with line geometries. Some of these geometries have a length of 0.0, but they have two points with the same coordinate.
I want to handle this features within a python script and tried to fetch all of them inside a polygon. When I use a QgsFeatureRequest,

```
feats = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(myPolygon.boundingBox()))
```

the result contains only features with a length > 0.0, but not "zero-length-lines". How can I fetch these lines, too?

In the QGIS application I can see those "zero-length-lines"and I can select them manually.
I checked this with a small script:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
fs = layer.selectedFeatures()
for f in fs:
    g = f.geometry()
    print("WKB type",g.type())
    if g.type() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
        print("LineGeom")
        print("length: ", g.length())
```

It returns for the selected features:

```
WKB type 1
LineGeom
length:  0.0   <----
WKB type 1
LineGeom
length:  2.996556190491762
```

Comment: loop through the features and check the length

Comment: I've just made a layer with two features in a unit square, one of which is a zero-length line, and something like your first bit of code, `feats = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(QgsRectangle(-1, -1, 2, 2)))` gets both of them. Are you sure your `mypolygon` contains everything?

Comment: @IanTurton the Q assertion is that when got with a setFilterRect on a polygon the zero-length features aren't returned, so can't be looped over. But my little test seems to imply they are returned (at least with a QgsRectangle query, which should be equivalent to a bounding box). Something's not right...

Comment: Such linestrings are invalid. Example: `select ST_IsValid('LINESTRING(1 1, 1 1)')` returns "false". Would you like to find them for fixing the geometries or why?

Comment: Thanks for your help! QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryNoCheck was it ...
Yes, I want to make valid geometries from this lines (the second point should get a new coordinate depending on other geometries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To also get invalid geometries you can try to set the [`QgsFeatureRequest()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRequest.html) to [`GeometryNoCheck`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRequest.html#qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryNoCheck) actively:

```py
# just get some test features...
lines = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('lines')[0]
polygons = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('polygon')[0]
mypolygon = polygons.getFeature(1)

# setup the QgsFeatureRequest():
req = QgsFeatureRequest()
req.setFilterRect(mypolygon.geometry().boundingBox())
req.setInvalidGeometryCheck(QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryNoCheck)

# get the features and iterate over them, it should also print length 0 of the invalid ones
linefeatures = lines.getFeatures(req)

for linefeature in linefeatures:
    print(linefeature.geometry().length())
```

Other attributes than `GeometryNoCheck` would be [`GeometryAbortOnInvalid`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRequest.html#qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid) or [`GeometrySkipInvalid`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRequest.html#qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.GeometrySkipInvalid), see https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRequest.html. *I guess you may have set `GeometrySkipInvalid` as default in your settings or something like that.*